# sed: replace found pattern with another pattern in the same line

Tags: unix, sed

I have a line like this:

```
"LExx 01236723 LE12"
```

I want to find `LE12` and replace `LExx` with `LE12`.
Is that possible with `sed`?

Comment: Please share the current sed command you are using.

Comment: BTW, the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Please clarify whether the strings *"LExx"* and *"LE12"* are constants, or might vary a bit, like maybe *"LEyy"* and *"LE99"*.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
$ echo "LExx 01236723 LE12" | sed 's/LExx\(.*LE\(..\)$\)/LE\2\1/'
LE12 01236723 LE12
```

**explanation**

```
s            # substitute
/LExx        # find LExx
\(.*         # save rest in arg1 (\1)
LE\(..\)$    # find LE and save next 2 char in arg2 (\2)
\)           # end arg1
/            
LE\2\1       # print LE + arg2 + arg1
/
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both search strings are [*constants*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)), then using *GNU* `sed` (running under `bash`) with the regexp extension `\b` (for word boundary):

```
sed '/LE12/s/\bLExx\b/LE12/' <<< "LExx 01236723 LE12"
```

Output:

```
LE12 01236723 LE12
```